# Is there any method to replace the access token of linked service in azure data factory using python?

Tags: azure, oauth, access-token, azure-data-factory, refresh-token

I want to replace the access token and the refresh token of the linked service once the refresh token expires using a python script.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no built-in refresh token mechanism in ADF so far. So,i suggest you creating a trigger to implement your need.

For example,using Time Trigger Azure Function because you know the interval of your token.Just set the schedule of Azure Function as that interval. Then use [Update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.operations.linkedservicesoperations?view=azure-python) with ADF python sdk inside Azure Function. Of course,this scheduled task can be replaced by other mechanisms you know.